# What is the difference between .msi file and binary version of apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, msi, binary

I am new to web programming , Could anyone please explain what the difference between .msi and binary version of apache ? Actually I want to use apache 2.4 I am not sure which version to download and use?

Comment: So you are a windows admin who has no idea what msi files are? Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.msi is the microsoft installer and has nothing to do with the apache webserver.

If you're about to download a binary .msi package of the apache webserver for your windows machine, go ahead. It just means that the windows installer will install apache for you. Or you could download the webserver and install it yourself. There's no difference in the end product, just the process of getting it running on the machine.

You might want to install something like wamp or xamp which will install a simple apache mysql php stack to get you going.

Comment: from binary files msi is prepared?

Comment: actually I am confused between source /binary /msi version,could you please clear it?

Comment: Source isn't compiled yet. You can make changes to the source, then compile it. Binary has already been compiled. If it's an MSI it's a  binary compiled from source with a windows installer.